# How to increase ScrollView height in Android?

Tags: android, scrollview

[image]

Hi friends,

I am using `GridView` inside a  `ScrollView` for displaying images. In the GridView I have 16 images which were dynamically added, but the `ScrollView` does not display all 16 images (see screenshot).

I want the `ScrollView` to display the whole `GridView`, does anybody know  how I can fix this?

Thanks all.

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="340dip" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="320dip" android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="@color/black">
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">

 <GridView 
                    android:id="@+id/jr_lookbook_grid" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:numColumns="4"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:columnWidth="90dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape"     

                    android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"/> 
</ScrollView>

                  <Button  android:id="@+id/click"
                  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                   android:text="Load More Pictures..."

                   android:textColor="@color/white"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"  />

</LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02_img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"> 

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
        android:scrollbars="none"  

    />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true">
</ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"     android:background="#AA000000" 
         android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"      
          >
                            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/back1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"

              />

                 <Button
                  android:background="@drawable/forward5"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="215dip"

                 />
</LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 36):

Use attribute `android:fillViewport="true"` in XML layout or use method `setFillViewport(true)` in Java code.

Have a look at : [ScrollView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport)

Comment: Thank you! This problem took me some nasty hours :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where I had a scrollview under a fixed Navigation bar on an AbsoluteLayout.

I set the scrollview height to the height of my screen less the height of the navbar.
My screen was 480dp high  and the navbar was 47dp high so I set the scrollview height to 433dp in the xml layout and moved the top of the scrollview down below the navbar using a Y offset.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="433dp"
    android:layout_x="0dp"
    android:layout_y="50dp"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Add the following imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.view.Display;
```

Now to make it work for multiple screens I added this to onCreate for the activity:

```
    ScrollView myScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    myScrollView.getLayoutParams().height = ((int) ScHgt(this)-47);
```

With the help of this helper function to get the screen height:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  public static double ScHgt(Context context)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //return the screen height of the device
public static double ScHgt(Context context)
{
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getHeight();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not add GridView into ScrollView. Please refer the [GridView API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) for understanding GridView.

As per the definition GridView displays the items in two dimensional scrollable grid. Hence, if you would add a scrollable component inside ScrollView the behavior would not be as expected. As we cannot add ListView inside ScrollView we cannot and should not add GridView inside ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

If the bottom part of the `layout` & top part of the layout weight are 0, then set the scroll views to 1 and use `layout_height="match_parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there is no need to add scroll view for Grid View. In Android, it will add scroll view automatically, if there is any need.