# Android ScrollView height is too short

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm new to Android have this problem making a scrollview that is supposed to scroll over a ListView of 10+ items.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.naqishop.naqi.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:entries="@array/options" />


        </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I can not extend scroll views to show more that one item at a time. I tried to tamper with `layout_height` of the scrollview  (like assigning the value to `500dp`) 
Also I tried adding

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

as  suggestd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4933531/5774375)
but it did not change the height. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: You can't use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for a `ScrollView` :-(
Set it to `android:layout_height="match_parent""`

Comment: You don't need a ScrollView. Just remove it. Just use ListView. It contains scroll inside.

Comment: @MichaelKatkov good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you've set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Replace that with 
`android:layout_height="match_parent"` and it'll take up the whole height.